# Initialize EF DbContext database within Ninject module

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, initialization, global-asax, dbcontext

I have an `InDocDbContext: DbContext` and an `InDocDbContextInitializer: DropCreateIfModelChangesInitializer` that "has been taught" to seed some initial data into the database.

I am trying my best to avoid putting an initialization code into my App_Start method in global.asax of my ASP.NET application.

I am using Ninject as an IOC container. Can I put Initialization logic inside NinjectModule or hide it in the context, so that I don't have to bring it to global.asax code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to context's static constructor:

```
public InDocDbContext : DbContext
{
    static InDocDbContext() 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<InDocDbContext>(new InDocDbContextInitializer());
    }
}
```

If you are using EF 4.3 or newer you can also simply define the initializer in web.config file. See [original 4.3 documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120708081919/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-configuration-file-settings.aspx) or [documentation for the current version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606.aspx).

Comment: But where would `Database.Initialize(true/false)` get called? Or is it not mandatory?

Comment: It is not mandatory - EF calls it when you use the context for the first time.

Comment: +1 for the static constructor, but I have my doubts on the web.config solution. Since Ninject is used for IoC, I feel uncomfortable with loading an assembly which may not be consistent with the injected assembly.